# Qual o critério que o site escolhe quando o fechamento tem motivos empatados?

Tags: suporte

Hoje me deparei com [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151084/28595) na fila de fechamento, e já tinha 4 votos, distribuidos conforme o print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha opção foi "Baseada em opiniões", porém a pergunta foi fechada como "ampla demais", mesmo tendo a mesma quantidade de "não está clara o suficiente", conforme o print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual o critério foi adotado para escolher uma das opções, se a que eu escolhi foi totalmente diferente?

Comment: Esse é uma ótima questão, realmente eu nunca entendi o critério

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O critério, normalmente, é a maioria. Porém, como ele votou em uma que não possuía votos, acabou deixando 2x2. Eu não sei dizer qual é, mas acho que pode ser algo com a data do voto ou "reputação" das pessoas. Todavia, estou vendo se acho algo no Meta.SE

Comment: @Randrade tem situação que aparece ambos, mas não sei qual é

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Aparecem as opções que foram escolhidas? +  de uma?

Comment: @Randrade acho que sim, mas talvez eu tenha me confundido com aquelas duplicatas que aparecem mais de uma linkagem

Comment: Na minha opinião essa pergunta merece ter todos os três motivos de fechamento escolhidos. É uma pergunta ampla, opinativa e que não está clara.

Answer (score 11):

[Vale o último voto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39664). Como o seu voto não desempatou nada, valeu o do último que votou numa das opções empatadas.

Comment: Não entendi o lance do citation needed rs. Mas então, sempre que houve empate, seja desse tipo ou se 5 opções diferentes forem votadas, o ultimo terá "peso 2" a escolha do motivo?

Comment: @diegofm o bfavaretto quer dizer que precisa de uma fonte para o que disse.

Comment: Citation needed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39664

Comment: @diegofm O termo [citation needed] é algo que você vê com frequência na wikipedia em inglês (na wikipedia em português o equivalente é o [carece de fontes]). O que ocorre é que nos artigos onde determinados fatos são afirmados ou descritos, há números ([1], [2], [3], etc) que correspondem a citações. Quando algum desses fatos não tem citação e deveria ter, eles adicionam esse [citation needed]. No entanto, alguns sites o usam de forma bem-humorada ou na forma de meme, parodiando a wikipedia.

Comment: É isso que o pessoal falou @diegofm, eu não tinha checado nenhuma fonte mas tinha quase certeza que era isso.

Comment: Obrigado @stderr, vou incorporar à resposta