# Quando uma pergunta é fechada?

Tags: suporte

Para ser fechada uma pergunta, pelo visto precisa de 5 votos, certo!?

Mas esses **5 votos devem ser pelo mesmo motivo** ou pode ser "variado"?

Exemplo:

- 2 votos **"fora de escopo"**
- 2 votos **"não está clara o suficiente"**
- 1 voto **"ampla demais"**

Comment: O voto é para fechamento. O motivo acaba mais sendo para fins informativos. Prevalece sempre o motivo mais votado ou em caso de empate, [*o motivo que tem o voto mais recente.*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5340/28595)

Comment: Esqueceu de citar o caso "duplicata". Que ironia, né?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Foi só exemplo po! rs 